# What causes "host process for windows services stopped working and was closed"?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, debug

When computer (32-bit Windows Vista 32-bit 6.0 Home Premium SP 2) randomly has a "**Host Process for Windows Services stopped working and was closed**" error:

[image]

This popup message simply occur out of nowhere at random times.

Is this something I need to be worried about?

What's causing the error?  How can I fix it?

Comment: Anyting in your event logs at the time of the error? That error is fairly generic.

Comment: Yup, it simply meteans that one of the instances of `SVCHOST.EXE` crashed. Unfortunately, that instance was probably hosting several services, so you’ll have to check the Event Log for more information.

Comment: Control Panel>System and Security>Administrative Tools>Event Viewer. Then once in, expand "Windows Logs" in the left pane, and look for errors around the time of the error in the Application and System logs.

Answer (score 0):

This patch has solved it for some people:
[An update is available to fix a Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS) crash on a Windows Vista-based computer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940520)

That error can be from almost anything, but if you want to just disable it, you can follow this link:

[Fix for "Host process for windows services stopped working and was closed"](http://forums.techarena.in/tips-tweaks/1092007.htm)

Make sure your system has all the Microsoft Update patches, and try to update all your drivers, especially for your printer since many people have related this error to their printers.

Comment: the patch does not solve my problem. my laptop is fully updated (32-bit Windows Vista version 6.0 Home Premium SP 2) . i don't have a printer. i definitely do not just want to disable that error message. i want to fix that error so that i do not get that error message not let it fail silently.